# Xamarin Android - couldn't find the .so file

Tags: android, xamarin

Can any one help me solve this particular issue, below is the error log:

> java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/hprt_printer_test.hprt_printer_test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/hprt_printer_test.hprt_printer_test-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libhprt_printer_model.so.

I searched through almost all the posts at StackOverflow but could not solve the issue.

Basically, I am trying to embed a jar file in a binding project and then use the .dll file in my project. For Information the structure of the binding project is 
[the binding project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWTIp.jpg)

The structure of the project is as follows
[The project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/79zrZ.jpg)

so is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added the .so file into Xamarin.Android library project [correctly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/native-libraries)?

Comment: Hello, Yes I tried even this by editing the .csproj file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin looks for your library .so files, in the specific folder called libs.

In your project structure you have folders called system, vendor. Inside these you have .so files as well. You have to place all these under libs folder.

Please refer this link : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/106178/how-to-access-dll-or-so-files-in-an-android-project

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am compiling both the projects, the jar binding and the main project using the latest platforms  Android 8.1. I am not using the build in emulators but using Samsung 7.